# How to use pip-installed jinja2 filters in Python

Tags: python, jinja2

In my Ansible project, I have installed libraries using `pip` that allow me to use additional jinja2 filters.

Among those, I have installed the `netaddr` library that allows me to use the `ipaddr` filter, like this: `<netmask>{{ interface.IP | ipaddr('netmask') }}</netmask>` (this works in my Ansible playbook)

The problem comes when I try to test my templates without having to run my Ansible playbook by creating a quick Python script. For instance:

```
from jinja2 import Template
print Template('{{ ip | ipaddr("netmask") }}').render(ip='10.10.10.0/24')
```

Throws me the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 945, in __new__
  return env.from_string(source, template_class=cls)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 880, in from_string
  return cls.from_code(self, self.compile(source), globals, None)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 591, in compile
  self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source_hint)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "<unknown>", line 1, in template
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'ipaddr'
```

I can see in that last line that jinja2 can't find the 'ipaddr' filter, which is 
installed in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, but I can't find how to use packages installed via pip directly in my Python scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this. Ansible needs to be in your python path

```
import jinja2
from ansible.plugins.filter import ipaddr

template_dir = 'path/to/templates'
fname = 'template.txt'

# get the filters from ansible/plugins/filter/ipaddr
f = ipaddr.FilterModule()

# for a template in your filesystem, set the loader
loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir)

# create the environment
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)

# *** Add the ipaddr filters to the environment ***
env.filters.update(f.filters())

# Set your template
template = env.get_template(fname)

print(template.render(ip='10.10.10.0/24'))
```

This will make your template file (containing `{{ ip | ipaddr("netmask") }}`) output

```
255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent the better part of an hour trying to get this working, and it was a total nightmare. I eventually had to give up. While it may still be possible, I wasn't able to get much of anywhere, even creating `Environment()`'s and trying to load extensions and whatnot.

What I finally ended up doing was to use one of the solutions mentioned here: [How can I test jinja2 templates in ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407822/how-can-i-test-jinja2-templates-in-ansible)

(That solution also mentions some online Jinja2 parsers, but those seemed to suffer from the exact same problems as the interactive Python method.)

What I finally went with was a combination of the **Ansible_3** and **Ansible_4** solutions -

I created a testfile called `nametest.yml` like this:

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
  - name: Test jinja2template
    template: src=name.j2 dest=output.conf
```

Then I put my test Jinja2 stuff in the `name.j2` file.

I ran tests like this:

`ansible-playbook nametest.yml --check --diff --connection=local -e role=api -e level=prod -e '{"item": {"private_ip": "1.2.3.4"}}' -e debug_instance=false`

Those `-e` options each set a single variable's value. Mostly I just used the simple `name=value` construction, but for the more complex, nested object, I used the JSON version.

Then to run with different variable values, I just twiddled the various command-line arguments to test all of the various branches of code I had set up.